# Hackerank challenges MYSQL query returns wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From this hackerank problem
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem?isFullScreen=true

Why won't my query return all the names of the hackers who have completed the maximum number of challenges?

My query gives all the names and all the challanges each hacker has done.

```
This is my query down below


SELECT am.name,am.names_appeared from (

    SELECT Hackers.hacker_id,Hackers.name,Count(name) as names_appeared from Hackers 
    INNER JOIN Challenges on Hackers.hacker_id = Challenges.hacker_id GROUP BY Hackers.hacker_id,Hackers.name
    
)am
GROUP BY am.name,am.names_appeared
HAVING am.names_appeared = MAX(am.names_appeared)

`
```

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rank to your inner query and keep only rank = 1 in your outer query.

```
SELECT am.name,am.names_appeared from (

    SELECT Hackers.hacker_id,
           Hackers.name,
           Count(name) as names_appeared,
       rank() Over (Partition By Hackers.hacker_id,Hackers.name
        Order by Count(name) Desc) as hackerrank
    from Hackers 
      INNER JOIN Challenges
        on Hackers.hacker_id = Challenges.hacker_id
    GROUP BY Hackers.hacker_id,Hackers.name

)am
XXXX lose this line XXXX Group BY am.name,am.names_appeared
XXXX lose this line XXXX HAVING am.names_appeared = MAX(am.names_appeared)
Where hackerank=1
```

Comment: so how come my query was not working especially the part                                           
   HAVING am.names_appeared = MAX(am.names_appeared)

Comment: like why using "Having" is not working

Comment: Because that is not how MAX() function works.  You are asking to calculate the max set of counts across your entire data set so you need a correlated subselect on that summarized temp data set to specify the range max() should operate over.  You would need to move that inner query into a CTE (With syntax) and then write a correlated subquery with that max() function in it.. The rank function is MUCH more straightforward .

Comment: your code gives an error saying Unknown column 'names_appeared' in 'window order by'